# Can a subclass have the same column name as a superclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have created database tables using the inheritance mapping. I want all tables to have audit columns.

[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Th7x.png)

Here is the code:

- An abstract Auditable class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable {

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
}
```

- a Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends Auditable {

    private String name;
}
```

- a Student class:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Student extends Person {
   private int grade;
}
```

- and a Staff class:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
public class Staff extends Person {
   private int salary;
}
```

My problem is only the `created_at` and `created_by` of the `Person` table are generated, but the `created_at` and `created_by` of `Staff` and `Student` tables are null.

Is it possible to have the `created_at` and `created_by` of the `Staff` and `Student` tables generated too?

Comment: What about putting the `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` to `Auditable`?

Comment: Remove @Inheritance from Student (and read https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having trouble is because this is a one-to-one association and not an inheritance.

This mapping is not going to work because when you use inheritance, you are stating that a `Student` is a `Person`, and therefore, the moment you create a student is the same moment you create a person. So, there is no reason to have those two columns duplicated among the tables.

But also, you are using `InheritanceType.JOINED`, basically asking to not share common columns among tables.

The only way this mapping makes sense is if those columns represent different
creation times. For example, when a person was born and when it became a student.
If that's the case, you can use this mapping:

```
    @Entity
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    public static class Student extends Person {
        int grade;

        @Column(name = "createdAt")
        LocalDateTime studentCreatedAt;

        @Column(name = "createdBy")
        String studentCreatedBy;
    }

    @Entity
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    public static class Staff extends Person {

        int salary;

        @Column(name = "createdAt")
        LocalDateTime staffCreatedAt;

        @Column(name = "createdBy")
        String staffCreatedBy;
    }
```

If this is not the case, then `Person` is not a superclass of `Student` and `Staff` and you can represent your database with this mapping:

```
    @Entity
    public class Person extends Auditable {
        @Id
        Long id;
        String name;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Student extends Auditable {
        @Id
        Long id;

        int grade;

        @MapsId
        @OneToOne
        Person person;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Staff extends Auditable {
        @Id
        Long id;

        int salary;

        @MapsId
        @OneToOne
        Person person;
    }
```

Where `@MapsId` tells Hibernate ORM that the column `person_id` is also the key for that table. Therefore you don't need `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_id")`.